# read / view the content of the cassandra commitlog

Tags: cassandra

I would like to analyze the cassandra commitlog files.
indeed, I have activated the cdc cassandra on some tables and I want to know the modifications made to these tables from these .log files

my question is if I can easily read the contents of the  cassandra commitlog file?
and how can i do it?

cassandra 3.11.10

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure - I work on the Scylla project

Trying to do a manual CDC by analyzing the commitlog of each node is going to be extremely difficult. Assuming perfect cluster health, I guess it would be a pain, but possible. But there are a million different scenarios involving combinations of partitions, node outage, streaming, repair, etc. that will need to be accounted for in your commitlog reader. Very tough to do.

Scylla is a Cassandra-compatible open source database that has built-in CDC, where CDC is treated as a system table, accessible by standard CQL. This feature is stable and considered "GA". https://docs.scylladb.com/using-scylla/cdc/

Newer versions of Cassandra also have CDC. Though I think it is all still in experimental mode and does require some sort of commit-log reader. (I'm not an expert in this, so others can chime in with better advice.) https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/cdc.html

Comment: actually i have a test cluster of only 2 machines..it's just for a test.

Comment: that's fine. but you still need to deal with partitions, failed reads, deduplication, etc. And what's the purpose of a "test" that only works with a non-production-ready system?